# How do I dissable Spring's Autowiring of specific fields in a class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Below is a class which uses the @Configuration annotation to create a Bean. I am slowly introducing Spring into a legacy Java application. I don't want to Spring-ify everything all at once - that would be crazy. I thought I'd start with one of the commonly used utility classes and I don't want Spring to create Beans for the three fields below (Enumerator, RandomDataGenerator, AliasMethodFactory). How do I turn off Autowiring for those fields? Spring is currently complaining that it can't find Beans for those (it's obviously trying to auto-wire them).

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRandom {

    private Enumerator enumerator;
    private RandomDataGenerator rDataGenerator;
    private AliasMethodFactory amf;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static CustomRandom buildRandom() {
        return new CustomRandom(
                new Enumerator(),
                new RandomDataGenerator(
                        new MersenneTwister(System.currentTimeMillis() * Thread.currentThread().getId())
                ),
                new AliasMethodFactory()
        );
    }

    CustomRandom(Enumerator enumerator, RandomDataGenerator generator, AliasMethodFactory amf) {
       this.enumerator = enumerator;
       this.rDataGenerator = generator;
       this.amf = amf;
   }

//UNRELATED INSTANCE METHODS FOLLOW...
```

Comment: What the right message error is? try remove `static` from your method. when you try inject bean you can set as not required on implementation eg. `@Autowired( required = false ) private CustomRandom customRandom` for not complain. in other way it is possible set conditions to `bean` with `@ConditionalOnProperty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate the class for the Bean and the Configuration of the Bean.
Like this

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRandomConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static CustomRandom buildRandom()
    {
        return new CustomRandom(
            new Enumerator(),
            new RandomDataGenerator(
                new MersenneTwister(System.currentTimeMillis() * Thread.currentThread().getId())
            ),
            new AliasMethodFactory()
        );
    }
}
```

and the bean:

```
public class CustomRandom
{

    private Enumerator enumerator;
    private RandomDataGenerator rDataGenerator;
    private AliasMethodFactory amf;

    public CustomRandom(Enumerator enumerator, RandomDataGenerator rDataGenerator, AliasMethodFactory amf)
    {
        this.enumerator = enumerator;
        this.rDataGenerator = rDataGenerator;
        this.amf = amf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you have created a `all-argument constructor` in your `CustomRandom` class. That's your issue. When `Spring` try to initialize this class it will only see one way, which is create the class using this `all-argument constructor.`

The fix is very straightforward. Add `no-argument constructor` to `CustomRandom`.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRandom {

    private Enumerator enumerator;
    private RandomDataGenerator rDataGenerator;
    private AliasMethodFactory amf;

    @Autowired // This is not needed, yet its better to add it show your intent
    public CustomRandom() {}

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public static CustomRandom buildRandom() {
        return new CustomRandom(
                new Enumerator(),
                new RandomDataGenerator(
                        new MersenneTwister(System.currentTimeMillis() * Thread.currentThread().getId())
                ),
                new AliasMethodFactory()
        );
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks but the constructor with arguments is not public. I'm not entirely sure why but the author wanted us to use 'buildRandom' to construct the object from outside of the class. Your answer would work if that wasn't the case.

Comment: @ac_ so is there no public constructor?

Comment: Package protected, just for unit testing. That's why there's a 'build' method.

Comment: @ac_ I'm not whether you misunderstood my answer. In my answer I meant you need both `no-argument constructor`  and existing `all-argument constructor` in your `CustomRandom` class. So `Spring` can use `no-argument constructor` to initialize the bean instead of `all-argument constructor`. And `no-argument constructor` must not `private`

Comment: Yes but the problem with that method is that Spring would also try and instantiate the fields and we don't want that.

Comment: @ac_ you mean `autowire` them as dependencies? If you can update your `CustomRandom` class with missing code it would be helpful.